# FedEx setup in Magento 1.7, Canadian Postal Code

Tags: magento, module, fedex

I'm trying to set up FedEx shipping on my Magento cart 1.7.0.2, and I have entered all the information, such as the weight of the product, my own shipping address, as well as all the information I have received from Fedex.com/developer (KEY, Meter #, ID and Pass), but I can't seem to view FedEx as an option during checkout.

I've had a look at other threads, but I can't seem to find a solution to my issue.

Also, should my postal code also be A3B 2C1, or A3B2C1 (without a space between)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably double check to make sure that your FedEx account is able to submit international shipments.

I have run into this before, though I can't recall if it was FedEx or UPS.

It will also be helpful for you to turn on "Debug Mode" which will generate a log of the shipment request/response under /var/log/.

Comment: through the debug, I've discovered that the Meter # is wrong.  I'll have to generate a new one in the Fedex Website